# Changing the connection string on multiple forms

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, sqlconnection

I have multiple forms in my project.  Sometimes I work on my laptop, sometimes I work on my desktop.  The problem is, when transferring my project from laptop to desktop and vice versa, I must change my connection string on all forms in the project.

This is my connection string.  I declared it globally.

```
Dim CN As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Documents and Settings\Adriane05\Desktop\ThesisDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
```

How can I change a single file without changing it on all forms?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, Ronnie's problem is that the string has got a local directory path.  An obvious solution would be to use a path that exists on both computers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways you could accomplish this. First is you could map your project folder to the same drive letter on all your computers so your connection string wouldn't change. I do this by default because my projects are on a drive that I encrypt with TrueCrypt

Another way is a simple code pattern. Store your connection string in a setting or global variable, and run something like this when your application loads:

```
if Environment.MachineName.Equals("laptop") then
    connectionString = ' Connection string 1
ElseIf Environment.MachineName.Equals("desktop") then
    connectionString = ' Connection string 2 
else
    connectionString = My.Settings.ConnectionString
End If

databaseProvider.Open(connectionString)
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the dumb question. Thx for this! now i can transfer my project from any computer :D

Answer (score 1):

Declare a global variable (or constant) somewhere and replace the statement mentioned in your post by

```
Dim CN As New SqlConnection(NameOfGlobalVariable)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to move connection string in `config` file. See these tutorials:

[Store connection string in config](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/store-connection-string-in-web-config)

[Connection Strings and Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx)